# Relative Path with Response.AddHeader

Tags: c#, .net, response.redirect

I am running a timer and performing a redirect after a user changes his or her password (AKA, notify them that the password was changed and then send them back to the home page).  However, I can't seem to do a relative path in the code below.  Listed below is what I'd *like* to do:

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;URL="~/pages/home.aspx");
```

Why isn't this working?  How do I get it to work?  (I know I can do relative paths in other parts of the site, but that is because it is running server side.)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an absolute URL for the REFRESH header. Take a look at [this post](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/154812.aspx) showing how to obtain an absolute URL from relative (you could use the `ResolveServerUrl` shown there):

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "2;url=" + ResolveServerUrl("~/pages/home.aspx"));
```

For reference:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method returns a fully qualified absolute server Url which includes
/// the protocol, server, port in addition to the server relative Url.
/// 
/// Works like Control.ResolveUrl including support for ~ syntax
/// but returns an absolute URL.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ServerUrl">Any Url, either App relative or fully qualified</param>
/// <param name="forceHttps">if true forces the url to use https</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ResolveServerUrl(string serverUrl, bool forceHttps)
{
    // *** Is it already an absolute Url?
    if (serverUrl.IndexOf("://") > -1)
        return serverUrl;

    // *** Start by fixing up the Url an Application relative Url
    string newUrl = ResolveUrl(serverUrl);

    Uri originalUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
    newUrl = (forceHttps ? "https" : originalUri.Scheme) + 
             "://" + originalUri.Authority + newUrl;

    return newUrl;
} 

/// <summary>
/// This method returns a fully qualified absolute server Url which includes
/// the protocol, server, port in addition to the server relative Url.
/// 
/// It work like Page.ResolveUrl, but adds these to the beginning.
/// This method is useful for generating Urls for AJAX methods
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ServerUrl">Any Url, either App relative or fully qualified</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string ResolveServerUrl(string serverUrl)
{
    return ResolveServerUrl(serverUrl, false);
}
```